# Schedule a task (update data) each monday in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a dashboard living in a Shiny Server pro that shows different analysis. The data is coming from a long query that takes around 20 minutes to be completed.

In my current set up, I have a button that updates the data:

1. queries new data
2. transforms the data
3. saves the data in a file .RData
4. saves the data in a global object (using `data <<-`)

Just in case, outside the server and ui functions I have a statement that checks if data object exists. In case that does not exists, it reads the data from the .RData file instead of doing the query again.

Now I would like to update the data each Monday at 5:00pm (I do not want to open the app and push the button each Monday). I think that the best way to do it is using a cron job using cronR. The code will be located in the app.R outside the server and ui functions. Now I have the following questions:

1. If I am using Shiny server pro how many times, the app, will create the cron job if it is located in the app.R outside the server and ui functions?
2. How can I replace the object `data` in the shiny app? In such a way that if a user open the app on Monday after 5:00 pm the data will be in place, without the need of reading the .RData file and of course not doing the query again.
3. What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create your cron process with cronR completely outside the shiny application and make sure it saves your data to the correct place.

Create the R code which gets your data:

```
library(...)
# ...
# x <- mydata
save(x, file = "NewData.Rda")
```

Create the cron job:

```
cmd <- cron_rscript("path/to/getdata.R")
cron_add(cmd, frequency = 'daily', id = 'job5', at = '05:00')
```

Comment: So far this is what I am doing. The thing is that when a user open the app, using ` reactiveFileReader()`, then the app starts reading the NewData.Rda and this also takes a minute or two. I would like to have the object in the environment, so that when the user opens the application, the file is already loaded and there is no need to wait one or two minutes for the file to be loaded.

Comment: If file reading is a bottleneck, think about better ways to store your data such that you can read things in quicker

Answer (score 0):

I cant't see your point 1. The app will not create the cron job if it is not named "global.R" or "ui.R" or "server.R", I think. Also, you don't have to put your code under the /srv/shiny-server/ directory.

For your point 2., check the `reactiveFileReader` function from the shiny library. This function checks a file's last modified time and the file is re-read if changed

```
data <- reactiveFileReader(5*60*1000, filePath="NewData.Rda", readFunc = load)
```

Comment: `reactiveFileReader` only does the check if a session is open, right?. I would like to have the object data already created.

Comment: Yes. `reactiveFileReader` update the data for the Shiny session to use. I understood that you would use an R file to create your data, launched by cron, that your shiny app would use, whenever a new session is open, or, if ever the data are modified duriong the session, with reactiveFileReader

Comment: "I would like to have the object in the environment, so that when the user opens the application, the file is already loaded and there is no need to wait one or two minutes for the file to be loaded". I had the same issue with an app. The only trick I found was to ping the app automatically at the end of the cron bash (after your data update, using, e.g. under Linux "curl -ks https://your site"). Also, I modified the shiny server configuration for this specific app with "app_idle_timeout =  0" so that it never idles (otherwise, you'll have to wait again).

Comment: exactly, I was thinking about how to ping the app to load the object but I have also seen, as you said, that the object is deleted when the app idles.